# Better way to Test API?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I have function :

```
def is_car_exist(make, model):
    
    url = f'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/GetModelsForMake/\
    {make.capitalize()}?format=json'
    data = requests.get(url).json()['Results']
    return any(model.capitalize() == car['Model_Name'] for car in data)
```

How write test to test requests method inside function ?

Comment: If you want to test `requests.get()`, I don't think that's ideal. This comes from `requests` library and is tested in that project. Test your code and logic.

Comment: but anyway , how implement unit testing to this whole function ??have I test requests separately ?

Comment: In unit testing, you typically want to mock any extarnal requests. So you'd mock `requests.get()` call with different data, status codes, and network conditions. For example: if `requests.get()` returns no data, what will happen? Perhaps you'll end up with an exception, because `json()` might expect some data on the input.

Comment: could you provide some example for  mine function ?